# First method being called by Advanced Database Crawler

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore6

Currently I'm using sitecore 6.6 and using advanced database crawler.
My sitecore environment currently is 1 cm on premise and 1 cd at cloud.
The ADC is working fine now.

Can I know which line of sitecore call the ADC method?
And what is the first method to be called by sitecore to ADC?
Which line of configuration in sitecore specifying the ADC's method being called?

Answer (score 1):

The ADC is a data access library, so Sitecore itself does not natively call it, you need to call it in your code for your front-end components (Layouts, Sublayouts, WebControls). The ADC configuration defines the name of your search index and what to include and/or exclude from it.

Here's an overview video of the ADC: http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/11/sitecore-searcher-and-advanced-database.html

The latest code base is no longer the ADC but rather called scSearchContrib: https://github.com/sitecorian/SitecoreSearchContrib